# Can one auto-complete http headers in fastcgi when using C++?

Tags: c++, http-headers, fastcgi

The title basically says it all. I've browsed across a few fastcgi (and just plain-old cgi) tutorials for using fastcgi to respond to web pages with C++, but they all manually write their http headers ([example](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_web_programming.htm)).

But there are [a lot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) of http headers, and figuring out what they all mean seems to be very time consuming, especially if one wanted to make a nontrivial website.

Is there a (built in, or not) method that can auto-generate the appropriate HTTP headers?

Comment: You do realize that the linked example contains just the single HTTP header `Content-type: text/html` ? No library can auto-generate that, they don't know you're going to create a HTML response. Many of the other headers are irrelevant: they're either request headers, not response, or they're applicable in special cases which aren't easily handles by a library.